# How to create a user that can only use scp?

Tags: scp

I want to create a user (named as guest) in my server where I can share my files with others, I only give the guest permission to use scp to get the file with the password I provide, he can't log in to the shell nor do anything else.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/83856/allow-scp-but-not-actual-login-using-ssh. Some very good answers there.

Comment: Also [Permitting scp but not ssh - without scponly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795649/permitting-scp-but-not-ssh-without-scponly)

Comment: Thank you all, it solved. I have voted to close my question.